# Is there a method to enter every subdirectory in a directory and perform analysis on file with certain extension?

Tags: unix

I have one directory, with multiple subdirectories. In each subdirectory there is a file on which I want to perform analysis (code already written).

Common for all subdirectories is that they have file with same extension on which analysis should be performed.

Using Unix shell, is there a way to write a commands which will:

1. for each subdirectory in main directory, use file with certain extension and perform further commands on that file (further commands include creation of some new directories and files)
2. repeat it for all subdirectories in main directory and files inside them

I will appreciate all suggestions.

Comment: `find` + `exec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `find` command. `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec prog \{} \;` will execute program `prog` with the name of every file in the current directory `.` and below with the extension `.txt` (i.e. that matches the pattern `*.txt`). The `-type f` excludes directories (and pipes and devices). The `-exec` means execute this command; the `\{}` will be replaced with the filename; `\;` means end of command.

This definitely works if your filenames have no spaces, quote marks, or backslashes in them. If they do, it gets a little trickier: `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 prog`, assuming the filename argument goes at the end of the line. The `-print0` means output the file with null termination (zero character) and the `-0` means input with null termination. `xargs` takes its input and invokes `prog` for every null-terminated word. `-n1` means only use one argument per invocation; you can omit it if the program accepts multiple filenames as arguments. You can use `-i` if you need to insert text after the argument.

Note: I am aware that using `-exec` for various obscure reasons may not be preferable for, say, secure system shell scripts, but for a use case like this it is fine.